# Combine 2 different Power BI .pbix projects into 1?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have an issue where I need to basically merge everything from one .pbix Power BI project into another different project.  The dataset sources are not the same.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean data models from different projects into one report? Or two reports that shall be combined? Is there a workspace involved?

Comment: Two reports being combined.  However the two reports have different datasets.  Yes I have a P3 premium capacity.

Comment: In which case my recommendation is to create a dashboard and show both reports as is on that. Users can still drill into reports as wanted. Load and reaction times will be as before for the reports and probably more responsive.